# How to move scrollbar of DBgrid to the top (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, dbgrid

Once I change some field data through an SQL update statement I need to see it reflected in DBGrid, I am not sure if the correct way I am doing is correct -> IBTable.Refresh. Anyway, it works for the moment, but the vertical scrollbar of DBGrid is moved to the bottom after the first refresh attempt, if I update and then refresh again, the vertical scrollbar becomes smaller and moves to the middle of DBGrid. I don't know how to update a value in some field directly by just changing it in the DBGrid itself, I appreciate it if someone show me an example of how to it.

How can I move the vertical scrollbar of DBgrid to the top position after IBTable.Refresh has been issued and select the topmost row?

My code is simple as I am still learning database (Firebird) and Delphi as well using example EMPLOYEE database:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //open IBQuery1, SQL command is in the component itself
  IBQuery1.Open;
  Label1.Caption := 'Tokyo''s budget was $' + TCaption(IBQuery1.FieldValues['BUDGET']);
  //clear all SQL commands as it's TStrings and remembers prev. added lines
  IBUpdateSQL1.ModifySQL.Clear;
  //start building the SQL update statement
  IBUpdateSQL1.ModifySQL.Append('update DEPARTMENT');
  if IBQuery1.FieldValues['BUDGET'] = '30000' then
    IBUpdateSQL1.ModifySQL.Append('set BUDGET = 500000')
  else
    IBUpdateSQL1.ModifySQL.Append('set BUDGET = 30000');
  IBUpdateSQL1.ModifySQL.Append('where LOCATION = ''Tokyo''');
  //execute SQL update
  IBUpdateSQL1.ExecSQL(ukModify);
  //close IBQuery1
  IBQuery1.Close;
  //let's see new field data
  IBTable1.Refresh;
end;
```

What I am doing is to read some field data from a select statement, and change it accordingly to the other value and vice versa.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Do you have any UI code you can share too?  This is just the button click function.

Comment: How about calling `IBTable1.First` ?

Answer (score 0):

*" I don't know how to update a value in some field directly by just changing it in the DBGrid itself, I appreciate it if someone show me an example of how to it."*

No worries. Try this simple configuration instead.

Place the following controls on your form.

1. `TIBDatabase` (Tool Palette - Interbase)
2. `TIBTransaction` (Tool Palette - Interbase)
3. `TIBQuery` (Tool Palette - Interbase)
4. `TDataSetProvider` (Tool Palette - Data Access)
5. `TClientDataSet` (Tool Palette - Data Access)
6. `TDataSource` (Tool Palette - Data Access)
7. `TDBGrid` (Tool Palette - Data Controls)
8. `TButton` (Tool Palette - Standard)

Now let's hook them up. Use the Object Inspector to set some properties so that the controls work together, like this.

1. IBDatabase1: set `DefaultTransaction` to IBTransaction1 (use dropdownlist in Object Inspector)
2. IBTransaction1: set `DefaultDatabase` to IBDatabase1
3. IBQuery1: set `Database` to IBDatabase1
4. IBQuery1: set `Transaction` to IBTransaction1
5. DataSetProvider1: set `DataSet` to IBQuery1
6. ClientDataSet1: set `ProviderName` to DataSetProvider1
7. DataSource1: set `DataSet` to ClientDataSet1
8. DBGrid1: set `DataSource` to DataSource1

Now set some other properties specific to your database

1. IBDatabase1: set `DatabaseName`, `LoginPrompt`, `Params`
2. IBQuery1: set `SQL`

Now activate a few controls. You can either do this at design-time with Object Inspector or write the equivalent code (eg. `IBDatabase1.Connected := True`) and place it in a button's click event if you like.

1. Connect your Database (set `IBDatabase1.Connected` to True)
2. Activate your Query (set `IBQuery1.Active` to True)
3. Activate your ClientDataSet (set `ClientDataSet1.Active` to True)

Now (minor hiccups aside) you should have a completely editable dataset in your DBGrid. Just click in there and edit whatever you like. All you need to save your changes if to write the following code into another button's click event.

```
ClientDataSet1.Post;
ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(-1);
```

This isn't the only way to do this, and there's plenty of room for improvement, but now you should have a good starting point from which to progress in whichever direction you choose.